# push notification success in console but not received in android device

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, push

i've to send push notification to android and apple devices, apple devices are getting the push notification but android not, its showing successfully sent notification but there's no notification in my android device.

following is my code, in this i'm sending one hardcoded device id and an API key:

```
var pushToAndroid=function(tokens,message)
{
    var message = new gcm.Message();
    var sender = new gcm.Sender('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
    var registrationIds = []; 
    message.addData('id',message.title);
    registrationIds.push('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
    sender.send(message,['xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'],2,
function (err, result) {
        if(err) console.log(err);
        else console.log("Send Notification Android"+ JSON.stringify(result));
    });
};

output:
{"multicast_id":6582780084434899000,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1426068793442479%b980d923f9fd
7ecd"}]}
```

kindly tell what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing is received by your app's BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: Hello,  I have the same problem, Have you find a solution?Thanks